# Why "bash <(wget -qO- https://example.com)" does not work used with docker's RUN command? But works both from host or container used manually?

Tags: bash, docker

I've create a simple vim distro and I install it manually in my local computer or inside a docker using a command like the following:

```
bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh)
```

This script works. But I want to execute it also inside a Dockerfile. Trying to simply add:

```
 RUN bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh)
```

I got

```
 => ERROR [ 9/10] RUN bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh)                                                          0.3s
------
 > [ 9/10] RUN bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh):
#12 0.321 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh)]: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
make: *** [recreate] Error 1
```

Then I though to add `\` before `(`.

```
 RUN bash <\(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh\)
```

The new error is

```
 => ERROR [ 9/10] RUN bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh)                                                          0.3s
------
 > [ 9/10] RUN bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh):
#12 0.310 /bin/sh: 1: cannot open (wget: No such file
```

Other question (and answer) in stackoverflow does not helping me.

Comment: `<(` is a bash extension. The `RUN` command is using `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: It's being run with `/bin/sh`, which doesn't support process substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN` executes the command using `sh`, but process substitution with `<(` is a `bash` extension.

Use an ordinary pipe

```
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: Now the command gives no error. Is not working for other reasons. I think the problem is due to what the install.sh contains. I need deep investigation and maybe another question. Thank you for comment and response.

Answer (score 1):

You could write instead:

```
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorario/newdots/master/install.sh | bash
```

Which doesn't require any bash-isms to work.